# Stack Overflow stopped working properly in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome

For some reason Stack Overflow stopped working for me in Chrome. I can't comment (when I press add comment, it just scrolls to the upper part of the page), the achievements button shows nothing first time I press it, and when I try again it shows information, but it is misplaced.

I tried it on several computers (with different Google accounts), and I've tried it in guest anonymous mode (to ensure no Chrome application is doing this), but I still have the same behavior. I've tried reinstalling Chrome, but it didn't help.

It works OK in Mozilla. I don't think it is caused by Chrome itself, because if it was like that, many people would have experienced that, so it's probably something special to me.

Tags also doesn't seem to work for me (no list, but I can enter something). Any tips how could I fix this?

Chrome version: 48.0.2564.103 m, OS: W 8.1 x64

Example of "achievements issue" (after I clicked it twice. The first time it just shows the lower pane as loading):

[image]

But I am more worried about not being able to add comments - as this is a functional issue. Also I've noticed that a lot of other things are not working. I can't press `show more comments`, etc. JavaScript seems to be working OK in general.

Chrome Tools reports `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a functionh @
full.en.js?v=8d6c5480ab33:3d @ full.en.js?v=8d6c5480ab33:3s @
full.en.js?v=8d6c5480ab33:3(anonymous function) @
full.en.js?v=8d6c5480ab33:2(anonymous function) @
stub.en.js?v=247b641c05e8:1j @ dca.js?pid=39266&cid=49544_680_:2k.add @
dca.js?pid=39266&cid=49544_680_:2v @ stub.en.js?v=247b641c05e8:1a @
full.en.js?v=8d6c5480ab33:2f.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3h.handle.i @
jquery.min.js:3
```

I confirmed the bug in a few other places beside Stack Overflow. So clearly, Stack Overflow has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: lol: 'I don't think it is caused by chrome itself'.  Really, because Chrome bugs were the very first thing that I thought of when I saw your title :)

Comment: @MartinJames I'd agree, but I didn't find anybody has the same issues, and chrome is used everywhere. I might be mistaken for sure. And I started to experience that yesterday

Comment: I suppose it could be graphics acceleration glitching

Comment: The error suggests that jQuery isn't loading. Is `ajax.googleapis.com` blocked where you are, or are all JS files loading fine?

Comment: @Oded In general JS seem to be working fine. Anyway I can check `ajax.googleapis.com` from Chrome? I can ping it :) Unfortunately I am not JS dev, so I have no idea how to test it better

Comment: If you can access the page from your browser, then that bit is OK. And given that FF does seem to work fine, it isn't something in our control or our end :/

Comment: @Oded When I go to `ajax.googleapis.com`, it redirects me to `https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/` You think I should report this to Chrome team?

Comment: @Archeg - no, that's expected. That you get a redirect means it hits the domain, so it is accessible from the browser.

Comment: @Oded Yep, I meant the whole issue. I should go with this issue to Chrome team?  For now I haven't found any site that is working weird except stackoverflow. Facebook for example works ok, I guess it has lots of JS there

Comment: @Archeg - I guess that you might as well raise it with Chrome, though it might be something else (OS, interactions with the OS, gremlins...)

Comment: Hit F12, copy anything you find there, paste it into your post here. (if the Uncaught TypeError is the only thing there, then you've already done this - but make sure)

Comment: @Oded, etc. `$.cookie` is not part of the jQuery core, so that wouldn't be coming from the `ajax.googleapis.com` CDN, but from `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js` (which presumably includes this plugin/method).

Comment: @Shog9 I've checked - the error in the post is the only error I see there

Comment: Are you using a plugin like HTTPS Everywhere or a proxy that forces SSL connections? That breaks a fair amount of stuff on SO and other SE sites, in my experience.

Comment: @EdCottrell Nope. I even used guest anonym mode in Chrome to ensure this is not caused by any plugins.

Comment: I actually faced the commenting problem with Chrome on another site weeks ago for a while, but since it's one time issue, I didn't report it. No problems commenting on other sites though (just letting you know that you're not alone)

Comment: Things to check: 1: are any of your extensions set to work in anonymous mode? (there's a tickbox in the extension list). 2: open the network tab before loading the page; you should see stub.en.js (which appears to be where jQuery.cookie (i.e. $.cookie) is defined (you may also want to check that the version you get has this definition). 3: do you have any Comodo software? (they've been called out recently for replacing Chrome with a lobotomised version: "chromodo") Other browser-replacing or hijacking software could also be to blame; basically anything which might inject its own jQuery.

Comment: I was just asking the same question and found this one. Does anyone have an actual answer to this? I'd rather not read 45 comments, some very vague

Comment: @Archeg just to add to this, Stack overflow is not the only one I noticed issues with. Codepen is locking up when you are coding in a new pen and open the cog wheel to add a CSS library. SCSS doesn't compile either in the editor. Everything works fine in all other browsers

Comment: @Dave Thanks for help! I actually didn't realize that some extensions can still work in incognito. So when I was running it in incognito - I thought I was testing chrome without any extension, which is a false statement. I turned all extensions off and it started to work correctly. Unfortunately I have no idea what was wrong as when I turned all my extensions back on - it still worked correctly. But that's a general clue of what to do for the guys struggling with the same problem - just turn your extensions off.

Answer (score 1):

I jumped the gun and thought Adblock was the issue for me.
Disabled the extension and everything went back to normal.

But after a reload the same issue still remained.

Went through all extensions one by one and found that Couchpotato was the culprit. Apparently it injects ads on keywords which then Adblock tried to remove and breaks the sites functionality.

Answer (score -1):

If you installed the userscript named **StackOverflow Hide Jerky** in **Tampermonkey** chrome extension, just delete it and adding comment will be back.

> UUID: 3b2a0a43-e375-4e8c-8eda-2f05bc8f459e
>
> Last updated:  Thu Dec 07 2017 17:35:30 GMT+0800 (CST)

Hope it helps!